# APP consume mucha memoria Android

Tags: android

Hola amigos tengo un problema el cual les explico.
Tengo una app Android en la que tengo varios arrays en xml y de los cuales cargo la información en la actividad detalles pero varios usuarios presentan problemas de sobre-consumo de la memoria android, a mi me queda claro que esto ocurre al momento de cargar las imágenes correspondientes y que se encuentran en la carpeta drawable de la app. aquí les muestro la porción de código donde ocurre el error

```
    TypedArray placePictures = resources.obtainTypedArray(R.array.places_picture);
    ImageView placePicutre = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    placePicutre.setImageDrawable(placePictures.getDrawable(postion % placePictures.length()));
```

El error ocurre al momento de que la app intenta cargar las imagenes alguna sugerencia?

```
Por si acaso este es la clase completa
       public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String EXTRA_POSITION = "position";
    RatingBar ratingBar;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);


        setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        // Set Collapsing Toolbar layout to the screen
        CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar =
                (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
        // Set title of Detail page
        // collapsingToolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.item_title));

        ratingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBarId);
        ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.calificado) + " " + ratingBar.getRating() + " " + getString(R.string.estrellas), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });



        int postion = getIntent().getIntExtra(EXTRA_POSITION, 0);
        Resources resources = getResources();
        String[] places = resources.getStringArray(R.array.nombre_coctel);
        collapsingToolbar.setTitle(places[postion % places.length]);

        String[] placeDetails = resources.getStringArray(R.array.coctel_ingredientes);
        TextView placeDetail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.place_detail);
        placeDetail.setText(placeDetails[postion % placeDetails.length]);

        String[] placeLocations = resources.getStringArray(R.array.coctel_preparacion);
        TextView placeLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.place_location);
        placeLocation.setText(placeLocations[postion % placeLocations.length]);

        String[] acercaDelCoctel = resources.getStringArray(R.array.coctel_descripcion);
        TextView acercaCoctel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.acerca_del_coctel);
        acercaCoctel.setText(acercaDelCoctel[postion % acercaDelCoctel.length]);

        TypedArray placePictures = resources.obtainTypedArray(R.array.places_picture);
        ImageView placePicutre = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        placePicutre.setImageDrawable(placePictures.getDrawable(postion % placePictures.length()));

        TextView textHistoriaCoctel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextHistoria);
        String[] historiaDelCoctel = resources.getStringArray(R.array.historia_coctel);
        TextView historiaCoctel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.historia_coctel);

        //Verifico que el cóctel tenga una historia en el el array de historia
        //de lo contrario desaparezco las vistas de la pantalla
        if ((historiaDelCoctel[postion]).isEmpty()) {
            textHistoriaCoctel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            historiaCoctel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            textHistoriaCoctel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            historiaCoctel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            historiaCoctel.setText(historiaDelCoctel[postion % historiaDelCoctel.length]);
        }





        placePictures.recycle();



    }


    }
```